# Render google reviews with place ID javascript

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I have to display google place review using google places API.
I already found the placeId but not sure how to use it to render the review. 
Any help? Thanks!

```js
let storage = [];

let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch({
  location: userGeoLocation,
},
function(results, status) {
  if (status !== 'OK') return;
  for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    
    storage = {
      position: results[i].geometry.location,
      placeId: results[i].id,
    }
   }
  });

   $("#review").html(storage.placeId.review);
```

new to JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain up to 5 business reviews (if they exist) in the reviews node of the place data return; you could would essentially be something along the lines of:

```
// Fetching reviews
    for (let i = 0; i < results.reviews; i++) {
        var author = results.reviews[i].author_name;
        var author_url = results.reviews[i].author_url;
        var rating = results.reviews[i].rating;
        var author_image = results.reviews[i].profile_photo_url;
        var text = results.reviews[i].text;
        $("#review").append(author ' + gave me ' + rating + ' stars and wrote: ' + text);
    }
```

As long as the results.reviews.length > 0; we have a review to capture; the snip above will loop through 0 - 4, or 1 through 5 reviews (if available); as per Google's sample you have only a few variables to play with as seen in the example below:

```
    "author_name" : "Robert Ardill",
    "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106422854611155436041/reviews",
    "language" : "en",
    "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T47KxWuAoJU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZo/BDmyI12BZAs/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba1/photo.jpg",
    "rating" : 5,
    "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
    "text" : "Awesome offices. Great facilities, location and views. Staff are great hosts",
    "time" : 1491144016
```

You can read more about this here:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details